# Connection timeout ERRO

Tags: ipfs

I added metadata using ipfs, but an ERROR occurred.

//Code

```
const ipfsClient = require(“ipfs-http-client”);
const ipfs = ipfsClient({
host: “ipfs.infura.io”,
port: 5001,
protocol: “https”,
});

const tokenObject = {
name: Epic NFT token,
image: “https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmexGL2pVe8dVkmm3soPXBMajvFkjFfjasoxwG2G9fTnR2”,
description: This is NFT token
}
const cid = await ipfs.add(JSON.stringify(tokenObject));
console.log(cid);
```

//ERROR

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUqLh.png)

Please help me.
Thank you.

Comment: Please add the text of the error to the question instead of using an image.

Comment: Hi @Sunlight1026, could you please elaborate on what are you trying to do, what packages are you using etc.

Some best practises could help - https://docs.ipfs.io/how-to/best-practices-for-nft-data/#metadata